# Find and Replace on Visual studio with keeping the number

Tags: visual-studio, replace

Is there way on visual studio to find and replace text but keeping the number in the string same?

For example, lets say I have a code that saids

```
fields[0].Value;
fields[1].Value;
```

And now I would like to replace it with

```
reader.GetString(0);
reader.GetString(1);
```

Without manually replacing every single lines of code, I was hoping to do it through find and replace dialog.

Is there any ways of doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to replace part of the expression but keep a part (like the number in your case) you can use the search and replace function (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>) set to use regular expressions (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>) and use these expressions:

Search: `fields\[(.)\].Value;`

Replace: `reader.GetString($1);`

This will replace all expressions on the form `fields[n].Value;` with `reader.GetString(n);` where `n` is any single character. If you want to restrict it to keep numbers only use `fields\[(\d)\].Value;`

For more information see: [Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

I tried it with VS2013 and it worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The reference document helped tremendously too! Now that I know how to replace a Named Group, I feel like I can do anything with regular expression!

Comment: @publicst119 Yeah, regexes can be pretty awesome (but also a never ending source of headaches :p )